# aurelia visual studio 2015 Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2015, aurelia, typescript1.6

I am using Visual studio 2015 community, I have configured Aurelia with type script and it working perfectly. But now the issue is I am not getting any kind of intelligence in VS2015 for Aurelia.  Typescript is inbuilt in my vs2015 and i have also installed web essentials.
Please let me know how I can get the intelligence for Aurelia in my typescript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make sure that the aurelia `.d.ts` files are included in your visual studio project.

steps are as follows:

1. get (copy) the aurelia `.d.ts` files.  this step depends on how you get the aurelia repos.  if you are using jspm, look in each aurelia repo for the corresponding `.d.ts` file.  aurelia metadata looks like this: `[somepath]/jspm_packages\github\aurelia\metadata@0.7.3\metadata.d.ts`.  if you are using the amd bundling strategy like [aurelia-typescript](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-typescript#aurelia-typescript), then you can look in [aurelia-amd-bundler/typings/aurelia](https://github.com/cmichaelgraham/aurelia-amd-bundler/tree/master/typings/aurelia)
2. in vs2015 solution explorer, select a file or folder in your project, then go to the top and click the button who's tool tip says: `show all files`
3. expand the location where you placed the aurelia `.d.ts` files
4. right click the files (you can group select them) and choose `include in project`

at this point you should get intellisense.  if you find you are still having issues, we can dig deeper :)